# Why is there an error: type mismatch in my code?

Tags: type-mismatch

```
class Club(val name: String, val stadium: String) {
    // Produces a textual description of the club (which consists of just the club's name).
    override def toString = this.name
}

class Match(val home: String, val away: String) {
    ...
}

val match1 = new Match(club2, club1)
```

Why doesn't `val match1` work?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: At a guess, [tag:scala]? If so, please [edit] and add that tag. If not, please edit and add *the appropriate tag*.